# Object not Fully Created until KeyListener is updated

Tags: java, keylistener

I am making a basic tile game. In my game, when the player clicks the space key, a fireball is created. However, the fireball is not fully created until the player pressed another key. In other words, if the player pressed the space key wile holding say, D, the fireball will hover over their body until they click another key or release the D key.

I have used test code in the fireball class to see that the class is initialized , however the values being passed into it are not done updating until the KeyListener is updated (I think). Why is this and how do I fix it? I just want it to be so that the second the space key is clicked the fireball is created.

The Player class:

```
public class Player extends MapObject{

//player stuff
private double health;
private int maxHealth;
private double mana;
private int maxMana;
private int level;
private boolean alive;
private Rectangle boundingBox;
private int direction;

private ArrayList<Integer>keyPressed;

//fireball stuff
private boolean firing;     //used to make sure player only used one attack at a time;
private boolean fireAttack; //used to limit fire speed
private int fireCost;
private int fireDamage;
private ArrayList<FireBall> fireBall;
private FireBall fireball;

public Player() {

    x = GamePanel.WIDTH / 2.1;
    y = GamePanel.HEIGHT / 2.2;

    width = 16;
    height = 16;
    boundingBox = new Rectangle ((int)x, (int)y, width, height);

    moveSpeed = 4;
    direction = 0;

    keyPressed = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    level = 1;
    maxHealth = level * 100;
    maxMana = level * 85;

    fireDamage = level * 5;
    fireBall = new ArrayList<FireBall>();

    init();
}

public void init() {

    health = maxHealth;
    mana = maxMana;

    alive = true;

    firing = false;
    fireAttack = true;
    fireCost = 10;

}


public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    g.drawImage(Assets.player, (int)x, (int)y, null);

}
public void update() {

    if(health == 0) 
        alive = false;
    mana = mana + 0.04;
    health = health + 0.015;
    if(mana >= maxMana)
        mana = maxMana;
    if(health >= maxHealth)
        health = maxHealth;
    if(keyPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_W))
        direction = 0;
    if(keyPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_D))
        direction = 2;
    if(keyPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_A))
        direction = 1;
    if(keyPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_S))
        direction = 3;
}

public void keyPressed(int k) {

    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
        if(fireAttack) {
            if(mana >= fireCost) {
                mana -= fireCost;
                fireball = new FireBall(x, y, direction);
                fireBall.add(fireball);
                fireAttack = false;
            }
        }

    }

    if(!keyPressed.contains(k)) keyPressed.add((k));



    for(int i = 0; i < fireBall.size(); i++) {
        fireBall.get(i).keyPressed(k);
    }


}
public void keyReleased(int k) {

    keyPressed.remove(new Integer(k));
    if(k == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) 
        fireAttack = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < fireBall.size(); i++) {
        fireBall.get(i).keyReleased(k);
    }

}
```

the fireball class:

```
public class FireBall extends MapObject{

private double x, y;
private double movespeed, velX, velY;
private int direction;

private double xOffset, yOffset;
private boolean oUp = true, oDown = true, oLeft = true, oRight = true;

public void setoUp(boolean oUp) {
    this.oUp = oUp;
}


public void setoDown(boolean oDown) {
    this.oDown = oDown;
}


public void setoLeft(boolean oLeft) {
    this.oLeft = oLeft;
}


public void setoRight(boolean oRight) {
    this.oRight = oRight;
}

private ArrayList<Integer>keyPressed;

private Rectangle boundingBox;

private int fireCost;
private int fireDamage;

private boolean delete = false;


public FireBall(double x, double y, int direction) {

    this.x = x; //default positions at player location
    this.y = y;
    movespeed = 4;
    this.direction = direction;
    xOffset = 0;
    yOffset = 0;

    width = Assets.fireball1.getWidth();
    height = Assets.fireball1.getHeight();
    boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)this.x, (int)this.y, width, height);

    keyPressed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}


public void update() {

    x = xOffset + 150;
    //xOffset += velX;    note: this was commented out as part of my testing. Without 
                          //the fireball moving it is obvious that if follows the 
                          //player at first.
    y = yOffset  + 100;
    //yOffset += velY;
    boundingBox.x = (int)x;
    boundingBox.y = (int)y;

    switch(direction) {

        case 0: velY = -movespeed;
                velX = 0;
                break;
        case 1: velY = 0;
                velX = -movespeed;
                break;
        case 2: velY = 0;
                velX = movespeed;
                break;
        case 3: velY = movespeed;
                velX = 0;
                break;

    }

    movement();

}
public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    g.drawImage(Assets.fireball1, (int)x, (int)y, null);

}

public void keyPressed(int k) {

    if(!keyPressed.contains(k)) keyPressed.add((k));

}

public void movement() {

    if(keyPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_W) && oUp == true) {
        yOffset = yOffset + 2;                                  //PUT IN PLAYER MOVEPSEED MAY NEED TO BE CHANGED LATER
    }
    if(keyPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_D) && oRight == true) {
        xOffset = xOffset -2;   
    }
    if(keyPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_A) && oLeft == true) {
        xOffset = xOffset + 2;  
    }
    if(keyPressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_S) && oDown == true) {
        yOffset = yOffset - 2;  
    }

}

public void keyReleased(int k) {
    keyPressed.remove(new Integer(k));
}
```

Thank you very much for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Is keyPressed(int k) called every time the key is initially pressed or every frame the key is down?

Comment: @user3238865 I believe KeyPressed(int k) is called everytime it is down. However, the player has to release the space key to fire another fireball becayse of boolean fireAttack. However, my testing proved that the fireball object is created only when the key is first pressed. I put a System.out.println() type of thing in the constuctor of firebal is it displayed when i clicked the key.

Comment: @user3238865 It doesn't matter, I changed the attack to click based because it's easier and it works :P

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting all of the stuff from `keyPressed(int keyEvent)` into `keyTyped(int keyEvent)`? Technically, a key is pressed whenever, but typing a key is both pressing and lifting your finger from it.
That may help you. Best of luck!
Side note: what you are doing with those keys is very strange. Why is your class not implementing the `KeyListener` interface?

Comment: It is passed the int(k) by another class that calls the player. Ahh sorry. I misspoke in my question. Pressing- and releasing- space does the same thing. The fireball follows the player until either WASD are pressed.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I changed the attack to click based because it's easier and it works :P